# Views within Views? How to generate lists of items with Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to build a list of items (eg. books) and I would like to then allow the user to filter this list (eg. by author). I would expect that each item in the list would have it's own view, and that the list itself would also have a view. I can't seem to "see" how these fit together in Backbone, however.

Currently, my code is as follows (coffee-script):

```
class Book extends Backbone.Model

class BookList extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Book
  url: "/library/books.json"

books = new BookList

class BookListView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    @template = _.template('''
      <ul>
        <% books.each(function(book){ %>
          <li><%= book.get('title') %>, <%= book.get('author') %></li>
        <% }); %>
      </ul>
    ''')
    @render

  render: ->
    template = @template
    books.fetch success: -> jQuery("#books").html(template({'books': books}))
```

What I'd like to understand is how to create each `<li>` element in the list with it's own view+template so I can filter them by author.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it's certainly possible to write it that way, things can get convoluted if you have templates nesting views nesting templates, ad infinitum...

Instead, why not insert your Book views into the list:

```
render: ->
  $(this.el).html this.template()
  bookHTML = for book in Books
    (new BookView model: book).render().el
  this.$('.book_list').append bookHTML
```

Comment: Thanks! How would one use Underscore's `filter` methods to filter the books by author?

Comment: Also, could you provide an example of how one would actually write a template nesting a view nesting a template? Just in case one wanted to actually achieve such a structure -- more for learning purposes than actual use. :)

Comment: <div><%= renderTemplate(moreData) %></div>

Comment: Books.filter(function(book){ return book.author == expectedAuthor; });

Comment: Will this approach leak BookViews every time render is called? If so, wouldn't it be hard to get rid of those views if they reference model objects that are still hanging around and valid?

Comment: Someone please answer Brett's question!

Comment: @jashkenas thanks - a whole bunch of things just came together with your answer.

Comment: @Brett, @Chetan: AFAIK, as long as nothing is referencing the `BookView` instances (as they are being used to just extract the `el` property value), they'll be garbage collected on the next run. It doesn't matter if the `BookView` references `el`.